# how stop auto reloading table view while scrolling table upward and downward directions in swift ?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I'm using table view for filling data and displaying same data in table with single custom cell(both viewing and editing). While editing what ever the data entered and scrolled top to bottom the data was entered in cell it was gone because auto reloading.

Please help me how to stop table auto reloading.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Please help me how to stop table auto reloading.

You can't -- tables automatically reuse cells that are no longer visible in order to avoid allocating many more cells than are actually needed. That saves memory and improves performance.

> While editing what ever the data entered and scrolled top to bottom the data was entered in cell it was gone because auto reloading.

You should never rely on views to store your data. If the user edits something in a cell, save that new information in your data model, i.e. wherever you're keeping the data for the table. You can save the data immediately, as the user is editing, or you can wait for `tableView(_ didEndDisplaying: forRowAt:)` and save the data before the cell is reused.

Direct editing of rows in a table is very unusual in iOS apps. The usual thing to do is to display a detail view with the data for that row, and let the user edit that. That creates a clear beginning and end to the edit, which makes your code simpler, but it also makes it easy for the user to understand exactly when something is being edited.